# Android Studio build error for new project

Tags: android, android-studio

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the Android Studio and when i created a new project I got the error stating files under build cannot be changed.Is this a problem with Gradle?.[image: This is what i got whenever i tried to create and build a new project.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your SDK, i.e. Marshmallow (API level 23). Then, choose `targetSdkVersion` to 23 and `compileSdkVersion` to 23. Finally, rebuild your project through Build > Rebuild project.

Comment: yea, got it, I downloaded sdk for lollipop and selected android 5.0 as target device and now it is working properly.

Comment: Only compileSdkVersion to 23 is required. You can use targetSdkVersion 22.